# POST request from submit button in admin log

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['is_external']

@admin.register(Submission)
class SubmissionAdmin(CustomAdmin):
    list_display = ('is_active', 'activate')

    def activate(self, obj):
        from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
        if not obj.is_active:
            return mark_safe('<button name="Activate" button type="submit" class="btn" '
                             'value="%s">Activate</button>' % escape(obj.id))
        else:
            return mark_safe('<button name="Activate" button type="submit" '
                             'value="%s" disabled>Activate</button>' % escape(obj.id))
```

I made a button activate in some admin log list. After clicking this button it submitting whole list and sends POST request to the same page with activate property an id of choosen row and I want to handle that POST. Can I do this in this SubmissionAdmin class and how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by creating custom **actions**

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['is_external']

@admin.register(Submission)
class SubmissionAdmin(CustomAdmin):
    list_display = ('is_active')

    def activate(self,request,queryset):
          for obj in queryset:
              #you can add the activate logic here

    def deactivate(self,request,queryset):
          for obj in queryset:
              #you can add the de-activate logic here

    activate.short_description = "Activate"
    activate.short_description = "De-Activate"
    actions = [activate,deactivate]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: thx, but actions are in the list in top left corner? 
its need to be button in each row ;/

Comment: I think you should use ajax for this then